# Visual Studio Code 1.79.1 launch in admin mode fails with code 18

Tags: visual-studio-code

After upgrading my VS Code to version 1.79.1 it is throwing error when I am trying to launch in admin mode. Without admin mode launch is working. Adding the screenshot of the error and the version details below.
[image]

> The window terminated unexpectedly (reason:'launch-failed',code:'18')

[image]

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) into your question post _as text_.

Comment: you'll have my upvote once you make the change I requested above.

Comment: @starball - Please find it below.

Version: 1.79.2 (user setup)
Commit: 695af097c7bd098fbf017ce3ac85e09bbc5dda06
Date: 2023-06-14T08:57:04.379Z
Electron: 22.5.7
Chromium: 108.0.5359.215
Node.js: 16.17.1
V8: 10.8.168.25-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22621

Comment: does the 1.79.2 fix mentioned in my answer post work for you?

Comment: @starball - weird things are happening now. When I am launching it from command prompt which is my preferred way it is throwing the same error. But if I double click the exe or launch through GUI it is not throwing the error and launching successfully. I will continue to use the insider build as I am doing something which requires it. I will test it again and let you know in a day or two.

Answer (score 4):

The workaround I found on version 1.81.1 with a system-wide install is the following.

1. Open an instance of visual studio code running as a normal user.
2. Launch a second instance with `code --no-sandbox --disable-gpu-sandbox`

Answer (score 3):

Googling "`github vscode issues windows administrator code 18`", I found this issue ticket: [Can't run as Administrator - launch-failed code 18
#185057](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/185057), where [a maintainer said](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/185057#issuecomment-1590220449):

> Please refer to https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/windows#_unable-to-run-as-admin-when-applocker-is-enabled for launching as administrator.
>
> Currently `--no-sandbox` does not work as expected which is being resolved in [#184687](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/184687) and fix will be available in 1.79.2.

From the linked user documentation:

> With the introduction of process sandboxing (discussed in this [blog post](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2022/11/28/vscode-sandbox)) running as administrator is currently unsupported when AppLocker is configured due to a limitation of the runtime sandbox. If your work requires that you run VS Code from an elevated terminal, you can launch `code` with `--no-sandbox --disable-gpu-sandbox` as a workaround.
>
> Subscribe to [issue #122951](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/122951) to receive updates.

Until VS Code 1.79.2 is released, you can try using VS Code Insiders with `--no-sandbox --disable-gpu-sandbox`.

Apparently updating to 1.79.2 has not fixed this issue for several users. I am still watching the issue ticket and will update this answer as the situation evolves.

Note that [in VS Code 1.80, there is a new flag, `--disable-chromium-sandbox`](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_80#_disable-chromium-sandbox), that can be used in the place of `--no-sandbox --disable-gpu-sandbox`, and some other related features that you might be interested in.

Comment: Thank you. Somehow I couldn't find this when I was searching. I actually tried adding --no-sandbox flag while troubleshooting but it didn't work as this issue describes. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: yup using --no-sandbox --disable-gpu-sandbox with code-insiders now to work this around

Comment: code-insiders is only working with --no-sandbox --disable-gpu-sandbox. Normal VS Code doesn't.

Comment: Release 1.79.2 didn't not fix the issue for me.  This is really annoying because I can't run a BASH terminal within VS Code that has access to Node and other higher privileged commands on my work computer.